# How to make item's title fade away

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm using jquery's tooltip to display the title of and item:

```
<a href="#" title="Delete" class="show-option" />
```

And JS:

```
$(function() {
$( ".show-option" ).tooltip({
    show: {
    effect: "slideDown",
    delay: 300
    }
});
});
```

The problem is that as long as the cursor hovers over the item, the title will be displayed. But what I want is a title that fades away after 3 seconds of the cursor being over the item.

I've been looking around for some solutions but nothing works, hope this is possible to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(function() {
    $( ".show-option" ).tooltip({
        show: {
            effect: "slideDown",
            delay: 300
        },
        open: function( event, ui ) {
            var timer = setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
                $(this).tooltip( "close" );
            },this), 3000);
            $(this).data('hidetimer', timer)
        },
        close: function( event, ui ) {
            clearTimeout($(this).data('hidetimer'))
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XSPAD/)

Comment: Seems to work on jsfiddle but I can't make it work. The scripts that I'm using are the bootstrap v2.3.2 (both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js), Jquery v1.10.2 and Jquery UI v1.9.2 and I make sure  that I load all this before my script. The only thing that seems to affect the behaviour is the jquery script, if I remove that the title doesn't pop up, if I remove anything alse still works, but like I said the fade away doesn't work, any hint?

Comment: I solved it, it seems like bootstrap and jquery ui scripts are clashing, what I did was load the bootstrap scripts first and then the jquery ui ones, that's the only way it works but I wish I could have this effect using the bootstrap style instead of jquery ui' css.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".show-option" ).mouseover(function() {
   $( ".show-option" ).fadeOut('slow', function() {
     // Animation complete.
  }, 3000);
});
```

Haven't tested it, but should give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

`$( ".show-option" ).on('mouseover', function()  {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
                $(that).tooltip( "close" );
            }, 3000);
    });`

There's a working sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/juaning/J9LSd/1/

PS: Guessed you were using jqueryui